# MVC Gui Design Plugin for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, model-view-controller, user-interface, gui-builder

I am searching for an Eclipse plugin which supports drag and drop functionality to build a GUI
**and**
supports immediate and automatic embedding within a MVC (model view controller) structure. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WindowBuilder](http://code.google.com/javadevtools/wbpro/) is free, simple and not cumbersome.  It also supports binding and synchronization of model pojo objects taking some of the MVC pains away.

I find it quite pleasant to work with as it does not places itself at toe forefront like most other similar editors will.  It does not embed strange files that serve no other purposes than to serve the editor, rather it uses directly the java source file as it's backing persistence and it does so in a very clean way compared to say visual Studio with an MFC project.

It does have some quirks though, especially with Maven as some of the dependencies are sometimes hard to find.  Personnaly I package them as a single jar and added it dynamically to the build through some clever hacks inspired largely by other members of the present community :-)

Give it a try, may not be the uber cadillac with shiny chromed everything but it does work well and stays out of the way when you don't need it.